# Trying to insert one column from table1 into existing column in table2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables : This is the clients table.

```
+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
|  id    |  name   | debt   | phone      | address      |  products  |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
|  1     | person1 | 55.54  | 8187654545 | Planet Earth | (none yet) |
|  1     | person2 | 55.64  | 8184256595 | Planet Mars  | (none yet) |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

This is the products table:

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------------+-------+
|  id | category |   name   |   type   | size_in_ounces | price |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------------+-------+
|   1 | liquids  | product1 | original | 2.7            | 1.99  |
|   1 | liquids  | product2 | original | 7.7            | 5.99  |
|   1 | liquids  | product3 | original | 10             | 7.99  |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

I am trying to add the `name` column from a row in the `products` table into the `products` column in the `clients` table. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is, on query, this to show in the `clients` table, and if possible for the `clients` `debt` column to increase in price accordingly.

```
+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
|  id    |  name   | debt   | phone      | address      |  products  |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
|  1     | person1 | 63.49  | 8187654545 | Planet Earth | product3   |
|  1     | person2 | 57.63  | 8184256595 | Planet Mars  | product1   |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

I tried to do this: but SQL gives me an error. I know the following code is wrong but it can give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
INSERT INTO `clients` (products) WHERE `name` = "person1"
SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `name` = "product3";
```

And here is another silly thing; if I do this code :

```
INSERT INTO `clients` (products)
SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `name` = "product3";
```

It creates a completely new client with every column null or empty except for the products column where it adds `product3`. Weird right?

Comment: `INSERT` adds new row to the table (weird I know;) - to set/change values in existing rows you use `UPDATE`. The thing you're trying to do looks flawed though. What that concrete product has to do with concrete person? What happens if two or more products match one person? If I get your goal right you should think of 3rd table "clients_products" (or clients_purchase), learn about "many to many" relationship and `JOIN`ing tables.

Comment: I wanted some dynamic way to add products to people, by reusing specific code. But thanks for your help. :)